Change citation brackets color using cite package in IEEEtran
I am using cite package for citation in the IEEEtran class. I need to change the color of brackets (inner and outer) to blue but leave the punctuations (comma, hyphen) color intact. E.g. \cite{b1,b3,b5,b6,b7,b8} generates [1],[3],[5]-[8]. I prefer to use the cite package and not natbib or any other package for citation and the citation style must remain the same as shown above. I tried this answer, but it only colors the outer most brackets and not the inner brackets:
\renewcommand{\citeleft}{\textcolor{blue}{[}}
\renewcommand{\citeright}{\textcolor{blue}{]}}

I also tried this but it changes the color of punctuations as well which I don't want:
\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1{\textcolor{blue}{[#1]}}
\makeatother

I tried many posts such as 1, 2, 3, 4 but none of them worked for me.
Here is the minimal code:
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Example Citations \cite{b1,b3,b5,b6,b7,b8}.

\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{b1} reference
\bibitem{b2} reference
\bibitem{b3} reference
\bibitem{b4} reference
\bibitem{b5} reference
\bibitem{b6} reference
\bibitem{b7} reference
\bibitem{b8} reference
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

which produces this output:

I want to color the numbers which the hyperref does, and the brackets (inner and outer) but not the punctuations (comma, hyphen, etc.). Any help will be highly appreciated. The expected result should look like this:

Update:
The square brackets are not part of the citation hyperlink by default. Is there a way to make the square brackets a part of the citation hyperlink? Then they will automatically be colored by the hyperref.

Do remember that you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is, instead of these random sniplet.

@daleif I provided minimal example.

You can color the brackets like in the following example. You can not make them into links easily if you want to stick to cite, for this you need a more powerful bibliography package.
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\citeleft}{\textcolor{blue}{[}}
\renewcommand{\citeright}{\textcolor{blue}{]}}
\renewcommand\citepunct{\textcolor{blue}{]}, \textcolor{blue}{[}}
\renewcommand\citedash{\textcolor{blue}{]}--\textcolor{blue}{[}}
\begin{document}
Example Citations \cite{b1,b3,b5,b6,b7,b8}.

\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{b1} reference
\bibitem{b2} reference
\bibitem{b3} reference
\bibitem{b4} reference
\bibitem{b5} reference
\bibitem{b6} reference
\bibitem{b7} reference
\bibitem{b8} reference
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}


